# Refresh or clearing form after submitting it in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a form in Google Apps Script and embedded it into Google Sites. How do I refresh or clear the form after it has been submitted? I am able to save the data to a spreadsheet but the data stays in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two things you can do here:

1. set the visible attribute of the FormPanel object to false.
2. iterate over each widget in the FormPanel setting the text "" or calling the widgets clear method, as the case may be.