# Multiple results from a single column search in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I just wanted to know if there was a way to pull multiple (only 2 at the most) results with the code provided below. All the code is doing is searching for a user's name in a spread sheet and then displaying the value in the cell next to that user's name. The slight issue I'm running into now is that their name might appear twice in a given column and I would like for both results to be displayed. Any help would be appreciated. The full explanation of what this code is used for can be found here if needed: [VLOOKUP style app script using UiApp and textBox form to reference a spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618897/vlookup-style-app-script-using-uiapp-and-textbox-form-to-reference-a-spreadsheet)

```
// function called when submit button is clicked
function submit(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(e));  // Log the input parameter (temporary)

  // Write the data in the text boxes back to the Spreadsheet
  var cell = e.parameter.userName;

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET-ID');
  var ss = doc.getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = doc.getLastRow();
  var data = ss.getRange(2, 1, 2, 4).getValues();

  var result = "User not found";
  for (nn = 0; nn < data.length; ++nn) {
    if (data[nn][1] == cell) {
      result = data[nn][1];
      break
    }; // if a match in column B is found, break the loop
  }

  // Make the status line visible and tell the user the possible actions
  app.getElementById('status').setVisible(true).setText(result);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is modify the behavior of the search loop. Perform the search, adding finds to an array, and get rid of the `break` that was terminating a search after finding one item. At the end of the search, join the array of finds into a string, and you're done.

```
// function called when submit button is clicked
function submit(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(e));  // Log the input parameter (temporary)

  // Write the data in the text boxes back to the Spreadsheet
  var cell = e.parameter.userName;

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET-ID');
  var ss = doc.getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = doc.getLastRow();
  var data = ss.getRange(2, 1, 2, 4).getValues();

  var result = "User not found";
  var result_array = [];
  for (nn = 0; nn < data.length; ++nn) {
    if (data[nn][1] == cell) {
      result_array.push( data[nn][1] );
    }; // if a match in column B is found, keep going, there may be more!
  }
  if (result_array.length > 0)
    result = result_array.join(", "); // concatenate multiple results

  // Make the status line visible and tell the user the possible actions
  app.getElementById('status').setVisible(true).setText(result);
  return app;
}
```