# Google Script: get values from input forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I implemented an authentication process using google scripts but with hard-coded data for `username` and `password` values from `payload` option and I can't find a way to get these values from the html page when user presses the `Login` button...

Is there a way to get this values from input fields to `payload` option?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
  <body>
    <form>
        <fieldset class='login'>

            <div class="required">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input-text" />
            </div>

            <div class="required">
                <label for="pass">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="input-password" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="Login" name='Submit' class='btn'/>
    </form>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#submit-btn').click(function() {
          google.script.run.login();
        });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Google Script:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Menu')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('login')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('SDR Tag Governance')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
}

function login(){
  var endpoint = 'login';
  var url = 'https://example.com/api/'+endpoint;
  var payload = {
    'username' : 'email', //Add here the value from #email input
    'password' : 'pass' //Add here the value from #pass input
  }
  var headers = {
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'Accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  }
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'headers' : headers,
    'payload': JSON.stringify(payload),
  };
  var urlResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(urlResponse);
}
```

I tried to add this code to the HTML page:

```
<script>
    $('#submit-btn').click(function() {
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
          return urlResponse;
        })
        .login({
           email: $('#email').val(),
           pass: $('#pass').val()
        });
    });
</script>
```

With GS function:

```
function login(email,pass){
  var endpoint = 'login';
  var url = 'https://example.com/api/'+endpoint;
  var payload = {
    'username' : email,
    'password' : pass
  }
  var headers = {
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'Accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Cookie':'...',
  }
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'headers' : headers,
    'payload': JSON.stringify(payload),
  };
  var urlResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(urlResponse);
}
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: Do not force tags into titles. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original HTML file you are not passing anything to the login() function in you .gs file. You can use jquery to grab those values.

```
<script>
    $('#submit-btn').click(function() {
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
          // this is where you handle the response from your Code.gs
        })
        .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
        .login({
          email: $('#email').val(),
          pass: $('#pass').val()
        });
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: login function in gs file

```
function login(data){
  // i dont think you need this endpoint variable
  var endpoint = 'login';   
  var url = 'https://example.com/api/'+endpoint;

  // since you are passing in an object in the html, you can
  // access the properties of data
  var payload = {
    'username': data.email,
    'password': data.pass
  }

  // this is the same as your original
  var headers = {
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'Accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Cookie':'...',
  }

  // are you sure you need to JSON.stringify the payload?
  // try just passing the payload object as is
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'headers' : headers,
    'payload': JSON.stringify(payload),
  };
  var urlResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  // Logger.log shows you what comes back
  // when that is fine change it to return urlResponse;
  // this will then get sent to the withSuccessHandler that is 
  // in your HTML file.
  Logger.log(urlResponse);
}
```

Comment: What should this function `.withSuccessHandler(function(response)` contain?

Comment: In your original login function, your last line is Logger.log(urlResponse). If you return that urlResponse then it will be handled by the .withSuccessHandler(). It becomes the response variable in my example.

Comment: When I'm debugging this code on .gs file I get undefined values on `email` and `password` values from the `payload` option

Comment: Can you rewrite your login function as: function login(data) {Logger.log(data)} and see what shows up in your logger? EDIT: I am thinking there is something wrong with you using JSON.stringify() on the payload variable that you are creating. I don't think you need to do all of that. If the data is being sent correctly to the login...

Comment: Check my updated question, this is how I implemented your code (at the end of the question). Is that correct?

Comment: Now I get the following error on .gs when I'm running the `login` function: `TypeError: Cannot read property "email" from undefined.`

This is how I'm running the app:
1.I execute the `showSidebar()` function; 
2. I enter the email and password and then press on the login button;
3. I run the `login` function from the .gs file

Comment: And yes, I need to stringify the payload object because this is how it works if I insert hard-coded data to `username` and `password`

Comment: It sounds like there is some problem with jquery grabbing the values to send to the login function. In the HTML file can you console.log $('#email').val()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114125/discussion-between-jordan-rhea-and-pavel-valeriu).

Comment: Jordan Rhea do you have an idea how can I display an error message on the html page if the fetching fails (wrong `username` and `password`) ?

Comment: Thanks, but I the following error appears in the console: `TypeError: google.script.run.withErrorHandler is not a function`

Comment: Oops, it is withFailureHandler not ErrorHandler. Sorry about that...https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#methods