# google.script.run.withSuccessHandler does not work properly

Tags: html, validation, google-apps-script

I have a HTML code setup within my Google Apps Script project which basically validates the userid and password provided that pair exists in the gSheet or not and according to the verification I either show an alert or redirect to another web-page. When I deploy the code as a web-app, HTML renders just fine, submit button works and executes the gs code however it does not return the value back to the **withSuccessHandler** function of JS inside the script tag in the HTML code.

I have read a couple of very identical queries in the forum and followed exactly the same path, however I couldn't be able to succeed. For example like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698752/google-script-get-values-from-input-forms)

It seems there's something that my eyes and mind cannot see - what is it?

Here is the **HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form id="user_login">
                <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" placeholder="enter username"/>
                <input type="text" name="pswrd" id="pswrd" placeholder="enter password"/>
                <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="LOGIN"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
           $('#login').click(function() {
              console.log("Form submitted...");
              google.script.run
              .withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
                 console.log(response);
                 if (response == true) {
                    window.open("http://www.google.com", "_self");
                 } else {
                    alert("Some alert message here")
                 }
              })
              .checkName({
                 userid: $('#userid').val(),
                 pswrd: $('#pswrd').val()
              });
           });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the **gs functions**

```
var html;
var verified;

function doGet() {
    html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('myformtest').evaluate().setTitle('Web App').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
    return html
}

function checkName(form){
  Logger.log("Form info > "+JSON.stringify(form));
  Logger.log("Userid > "+form.userid);
  Logger.log("Pwd > "+form.pswrd);
  verified = false;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1rard7vdpjmfrN81oi2ARhMlLGdNSxC7MqoIw2soj25E").getSheetByName("names");
  var values = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(n=1;n<values.length;++n){
    var username = values[n][0]; // 1 is the index of the column starting from 0
    var password = values[n][1];
    Logger.log("username: "+username+" | password: "+password);
    if (username == form.userid && password == form.pswrd) {
      Logger.log("User found in Row("+(n + 1)+")");
      verified = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  Logger.log("User verified? "+verified);
  return verified
}
```

I can log that the JS is fired correctly with passing the form parameters to the gs function correctly and the gs function executed correctly as well. However, it does not return the **true/false** value back to the handler function inside the JS.

I expect that when the **checkName** function is executed, to return the variable's value back to the JS that is to be processed within the **withSuccessHandler** function and resulting with either redirecting to a definite URL or displaying an alert message.

Comment: Show logs in the browser dev tools console.

Comment: If the values of column "A" and "B" are the same with `form.userid` and `form.pswrd`, respectively, I think that your script works. But I think that Google cannot be opened with `_self`. So how about testing `_blank` instead of `_self`?

Comment: @Tanaike it's not working with the `_blank` either. I have even tried with removing it completely.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation. In order to replicate your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including your script for replicating your current issue? By this, we can confirm it. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Tanaike sure thing. There is no any PI, it's just a test gSheet already which I will port the code to a gSheet in a different account. Here is the gSheet for you and it's already publicly shared. [gSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rard7vdpjmfrN81oi2ARhMlLGdNSxC7MqoIw2soj25E/edit#gid=787435020)

Comment: @Tanaike you will notice the **log** tab in the gSheet which the script execution log and the **names** tab is where I list the userids and pwds for verification. FYI.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your shared Spreadsheet, when the input values are the same with the values of Spreadsheet, `response` is `true`. But, when "LOGIN" button is clicked, `window.open()` doesn't work due to `type="submit"`. So for example, how about putting `return false` after `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(###).checkName(###)`?

Comment: @Tanaike worked like a charm!!! Your da man!! With my excuse, can you briefly explained the reason behind this solution?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I had updated my latest comment by including the explanation. Could you please confirm it by reload your browser?

Comment: When `return false` is used, the submit event is stopped. By this, `window.open()` works. For example, instead of `return false`, you can also modify `<input type="submit"` to `<input type="button"`.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you very much for your help and time to help me! It's highly appreciated my friend. Again thanks a lot both for that simple solution and the explanation.

Comment: I now understood why there is a slight delay when the withSuccessHandler's function is executed to either redirect or alert! Thanks bud, enlightened a lot!