# How to append html in sidebar templates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have created one `html` template file for show [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showsidebaruserinterface).

I tried `document.getElementById` for append dynamic html content but it's give me below error.

> ReferenceError: "document" is not defined.

**InformationTpl.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <base target="_top">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="errors"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Code.gs**

```
var getElement = document.getElementById("errors");
    getElement.html("<hr> Hii World !!!</hr>");
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('InformationTpl').setTitle("Attention").setWidth(300);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
```

Question : How do I get element from `html` template and append some dynamic info in this ?

Thanks ! 
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value of html text box in Apps Script function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525553/get-value-of-html-text-box-in-apps-script-function)

Comment: @TheMaster yes but as in solution uses `click` event and call function. But I don't have any events and using [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showsidebaruserinterface) to how template.

Comment: Where will the dynamic content come from?

Comment: `document` is in client side. So, you can use `document.getElementById` in the html file